# PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm running the following the script -

```
DECLARE
    new_vendor_id    vendors5.vendor_id%TYPE;
    new_invoice_id   invoices5.invoice_id%TYPE;
    current_date     DATE := SYSDATE;
    due_date         DATE := SYSDATE+30;
    iterator         NUMBER := 1 ;
```

Output:

```
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 6, column 34:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:

   begin function pragma procedure subtype type <an identifier>
   <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> current cursor delete
   exists prior
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

Please tell me what I did wrong. I tried to change to NUMBER(1), but It had same error.

Comment: For clarity, you should really use the formatting tools available. For example: highlighting code as code, and spacing each statement helps tremendously.

Answer (score 2):

If this is the whole script, then it should be throwing an error. Every block needs to contain at least three elements.

```
BEGIN -- Execution start
   NULL; -- A statement (even if it doesn't do anything)
END; -- Ends and executes the block.
/
```

The optional `DECLARE` section would go above the `BEGIN`, but it cannot be alone. Finish coding the block and this particular error will be resolved.